# ngClass is removing select options on load

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I have created a table where each cell has a dropdown with options 1, 2, 3, and 4. The sum of each row's selected options should equal 10. I have added an `ngClass` to each row with:

```
<tr [ngClass]="{'error': rowResults[0] != 10}">
  ...
</tr>
```

However, adding this `ngClass` has removed the options from being displayed from each dropdown on load.

How can I solve this?

I have created a [StackBlitz for this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sckpm9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't declare your array *rowResults*, so you should declare it at top of the SurveyComponent.

Also the error you get says:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

So it tries to read first element of property `rowResults`, which is not yet defined, because you define this array in your *continue()* method.

You should assign initial value of *rowResults* to make it work:

`export class SurveyComponent implements OnInit {
  rowResults = [];
  ....
}`

Also, you have a lot of repeating code, like select options, or rows in your table, so i recommend using angular directive [**ngFor*](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor)

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong about the cause and what is the actual output. Options are **not hidden** nor removed, but they are **not rendered** at all because there is an exception in rendering phase (missing field declaration). Rendering is stopped at some point. So what you see is only partially rendered markup, thus missing options.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-djtsmb